# Modifying a print-only function to create a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I use the following function to retrieve and print some database records:

```
jira_server = 'https://jira.firm.com'
session = JIRA(server = jira_server, basic_auth=(<user_name>, <password>))
query = 'project = MED and issuetype = incident'

def get_issues(session, query):
    block_size = 50
    block_num = 0
    start = 0

    all_issues = []

    while True:
        issues = session.search_issues(query, start, block_size, expand='changelog')
        if len(issues) == 0:
            break
        start += len(issues)
        for issue in issues:
            all_issues.append(issue)

    issues = pd.DataFrame(issues)

    for issue in all_issues:

        changelog = issue.changelog
        for history in changelog.histories:
            for item in history.items:
                if item.field == 'status' and item.toString == 'Pending Approval':
                    print('Key':, issue.key, 'Approved:', history.created, 'By:', history.author)

    return issues
```

This function merely prints the following:

```
Key: MED-84   Created: 2021-03-17T17:15:22.103-0500   By: Smith, John
Key: MED-84   Created: 2021-03-16T14:52:02.747-0600   By: Jones, Mary
Key: MED-71   Created: 2021-03-15T17:17:32.939-0600   By: Williams, Dan
Key: MED-71   Created: 2021-03-12T15:05:57.581-0500   By: Lee, James
Key: MED-71   Created: 2021-03-08T09:43:19.384-0600   By: Davis, Ruth
```

Is it possible to modify this function such that the `issues` dataframe is populated with the records? (e.g. using `issues = issues.append(...)`)?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this function already returns a dataframe? (`issues` is a dataframe)

Comment: Yes, `issues` is a dataframe, but there is nothing in it.  The question is:  "how to populate the 'issues` with the records?"

Comment: The `issues` variable line 13 is a list? What type of elements does it contain?

Comment: When I print the `issues` variable (on line 13), I get an empty list.

Comment: Mmmmh, if `issues` line 13 is empty, then all_issues is also empty right?

Comment: No, the `all_issues` variable contains the two records, as such:  `[<JIRA Issue: key='MED-84, id='3839'>, <JIRA Issue: key='MED-71, id='3704'>]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer proposed by @HenriChab will error unless `ignore_index=True`.  With `ignore_index=True`, that solution returns an empty dataframe.

Here is the answer:

```
jira_server = 'https://jira.firm.com'
session = JIRA(server = jira_server, basic_auth=(<user_name>, <password>))
query = 'project = MED and issuetype = incident'

def get_issues(session, query):
    block_size = 50
    block_num = 0
    start = 0

    all_issues = []

    while True:
        issues = session.search_issues(query, start, block_size, expand='changelog')
        if len(issues) == 0:
            break
        start += len(issues)
        for issue in issues:
            all_issues.append(issue)

    issues = pd.DataFrame(issues)

    for issue in all_issues:

        changelog = issue.changelog
        for history in changelog.histories:
            for item in history.items:
                if item.field == 'status' and item.toString == 'Pending Approval':
#                    print('Key':, issue.key, 'Approved:', history.created, 'By:', history.author)

                    d = {
                         'Key'      : issue.key,
                         'Approved' : history.created,
                         'By'       : history.author
                        }

                    fields = issue.fields
                    issues = issues.append(d, ignore_index=True)

    return issues
```

The output is as expected:

```
res = get_issues(session, query)
type(res)   
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by doing the following:

```py
def get_issues(session, query):
    # ...
    issues = []

    for issue in all_issues:
        changelog = issue.changelog
        for history in changelog.histories:
            for item in history.items:
                if item.field == 'status' and item.toString == 'Pending Approval':
                    issues.append({'Key': issue.key, 'Approved': history.created, 'By': history.author})
    return pd.DataFrame(issues)
```

Is it what you want?